# How to use the HP Procurve 2626 link-test feature?

Tags: switch

I have a HP procurve 2626 in one location and I see it has a nice *link-test* feature.

I tried it in all possible ways but did not manage to get it to work, used it on multiple PCs, routers, IP camera addresses but it doesn't get responses from the devices, even if I know they are 'UP'.

Any ideas as to why this might happen? Do I need to enable some sort of feature on the NIC's I am targeting?

Answer (score 1):

```
sh cdp nei
get mac-address

linktest mac-address
```

(no separators)